# Advice for using multilingual model to improve translation

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, translation, multilingual, transformer-model

I am working on a project that tries to improve low-resource language translation. Here is an example:

Suppose I am trying to translate German to English. To make it realistic, the data is limited to 20,000 german sentences and english translations.

I want to train a sequence to sequence model for translation. So, would training a multilingual many-to-one model on languages related to German, like Danish, Dutch, Afrikaans, etc... improve the quality of my English to German translation.

If anyone has any ideas or recommendations, please let me know. Thank you